# Symfony 2 split less file

Tags: symfony, less, assetic

I am building a website with Symfony 2 and using Less, like this

index.html.twig:

```
{% stylesheets
    '@AcmeWebappBundle/Resources/public/css/website.less'
    filter='?yui_css'
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

config.yml:

```
assetic:
    filters:
        lessphp:
            file: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/lessphp/lessc.inc.php
            apply_to: "\.less$"
```

Now the file `website.less` was growing a lot so I decided to split it into different files, like this:

```
{% stylesheets
    '@AcmeWebappBundle/Resources/public/css/mixins.less'
    '@AcmeWebappBundle/Resources/public/css/general.less'
    '@AcmeWebappBundle/Resources/public/css/tasks.less'
    '@AcmeWebappBundle/Resources/public/css/notes.less'
    filter='?yui_css'
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

The file `mixins.less` contains all the `mixins` I use across the other files.

The problem is that if I reference a mixin in `notes.less`, that is not recognised - I believe that is because Assetic seaches for mixins only inside the file it is compiling.
By the way, I am using lessphp, not node.js.

How can I solve my problem? How can I have different Less files using mixins declared in the mixins.less file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example you need to keep the website.less and just have it import all the relevant less files, like this:

website.less:

```
/* import the necessary less files */
@import "mixins.less";
@import "general.less";
@import "tasks.less";
@import "notes.less";
```

index.html.twig:

```
{% stylesheets
    '@AcmeWebappBundle/Resources/public/css/website.less'
    filter='?yui_css'
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

This way you can have several less files for your controllers or bundles which live in the same bundle, just importing the relevant files needed for the markup (for instance `frontend.less`, `backend.less`, `mobile.less`).

I encourage you to look at how Twitter Bootstrap [handles imports and separates everything nicely](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/bootstrap.less).